# Chrome: Edit html with external editor

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, html, text-editors

I have Chrome browser Version 52.0.2743.116 m, and I need to know if there is an extension or a tweak that allows me to open any page in an external editor software (that I already have on the pc)? (mainly for local html files).

There are some extensions to "open with" like "[open with Firefox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-firefox/poeacjbaiakjnaepdjgggojcjoajakmd?itemlang&q=editor)", however, I can't change the path to my editor.  There is also a similar addon in Firefox called "[openwith](https://github.com/darktrojan/openwith)", and I need the same for Chrome.

Comment: Why don't you simply save it?

Comment: sorry, I need it mainly for local files on the same pc) - my website files.

Comment: Then it makes even less sense.  If you already have them saved locally and possibly open in your editor, why would you need Chrome to do anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2359/chrome-extension-for-open-this-uri-with#).

Well, you could try this extension called [Open with external application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-external-applic/hccmhjmmfdfncbfpogafcbpaebclgjcp). But the problem is that you have to set a target application like: Firefox, Opera etc.

For Firefox there is already an extension called [Open In Firefox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-firefox/jmjejjdalfogiopknpabihjhplfkjjjk)

Yes, you will only be able to set one application.

Comment: thanks,, it gives the following message in the web store: This application is not supported on this computer. Installation has been disabled. The following problems are detected: NPAPI plugin is required by this app (and it is being phased out)

Comment: Paste this: **chrome://flags/#enable-npapi** to your url bar, Find **Enable NPAPI Mac, Windows** and click "Enable". Click **Relaunch Now** at the bottom. See if this works.

Comment: Update:  There is no longer an NPAPI in Chrome 45, since 1 Sep 2015. So this plug-in has stopped working.